# How to create global variables using Provider Package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter app needs a global variable that is not displayed(so no UI changes) but it needs to run a function everytime it is changed. I've been looking through tutorials etc. but they all seem to be for much more complicated uses than what I need and I'd prefer to use the simplest approach that is still considered "good practice".

Roughly what I am trying to do:

```
//inside main.dart
int anInteger = 0;

int changeInteger (int i) = {
  anInteger = i;
  callThisFunction();
}

//inside another file
changeInteger(9);
```

Comment: Where is `callThisFunction()`? Is it in another widget or it's not related to a widget at all? Can you provide an example of what this function would be?

Comment: The call function would work anywhere, it is just playing a sound through the flutter audioplayer plugin

Comment: Ok then my answer would definitely work for you.

Comment: yep I just tried it and it works great thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a new `Class` in a new file to store the global variable and its related methods. Whenever you want to use this variable, you need to import this file. The global variable and its related methods need to be `static`. Pay attention to the `callThisFunction` that you mentioned in your question, it needs to be static as well (since it would be called in a static context). e.g.

***file: globals.dart***

```
class Globals {
  static var anInteger = 0;
  static printInteger() {
    print(anInteger);
  }
  static changeInteger(int a) {
    anInteger = a;
    printInteger(); // this can be replaced with any static method
  }
}
```

***file: main.dart***

```
import 'globals.dart';
...
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
     Globals.changeInteger(9);
  },
...
```